# Contained elements to take on hover properties of parent element

Tags: html, css

My scenario is I want the hover effects of the parent element to be applied to the child elements, effectively over-riding styling settings of the children, and I want to this to be strictly CSS. I can do it easily enough with javascript, but is there a pure CSS approach? Thanks for any suggestions.

```css
div {
}

div:hover {
    background-color: red;
    /*change contained span backgound-color to red as well*/
}

span {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>When I mouse over this div, I want the <span>the contained span background</span> to take on the hover settings of the parent div.</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then add another **hover** specifying all-child elements as `*`, applying the inheritance rule.

```
div:hover * {
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

Snippet:

```css
div {
}

div:hover {
    background-color: red;
    /*change contained span backgound-color to red as well*/
}

div:hover * {
    background-color: inherit;
}

span {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>When I mouse over this div, I want the <span>the contained span background</span> to take on the hover settings of the parent div.</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @LenWhite, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
}



span {
    background-color: yellow;
}

div:hover span {
    background-color: red;
    /*change contained span backgound-color to red as well*/
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div>When I mouse over this div, I want the <span>the contained span background</span> to take on the hover settings of the parent div.</div>
```